# Laravel Social Referral tracking

Tags: php, facebook, email, laravel, laravel-5

You may have heard of Untorch.com - A fully automated referral program for email signups.

They use social sharing and emails to allow users to 'share' to get the word out about their product/service. **The problem boils down to tracking.**

I have chosen laravel for its simplicity and socialite (the OAuth package for social networks) to allow me to get users emails etc. When a user is authenticated they are given a URL in a view with their hashed email as a URL to share. 
For Example www.mywebsite.com/share/9H&GxdF

I can check if a user is authenticated or not on that URL above as the original sharer, its the tracking of who they refer is a problem. I don't know what the Database will look like to track referrals.

Would it be possible to grab a user's share code like '9H&GxdF' above and when the referral hits the home page it has a url of www.mywebsite.com?9H&GxdF or www.mywebsite.com/9H&GxdF. Then if it's a new user link them to a referee's share code and store in the database?

**1.Is this the correct way to do it? 
2.Is there anyway to detect fraudulent email addresses and fake accounts? 
3.Any idea's on how i could implement those types of fraud/fake detection?**

Comment: First of all, I hope you are aware that you are not allowed to reward users for sharing your stuff in any way – right?

Comment: Im quoting facebook - " It remains acceptable to incentivize people to login to your app, checkin at a place or enter a promotion on your app's Page" This means i am getting users to login with OAuth then enter a promotion

Comment: https://community.offerpop.com/docs/DOC-1138 - this only applys to a page